# THREE javascript weird behavior when pushing mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

Bear with me, I'm a total javascript and THREE newby. I have this bit of code here where I'm trying to push meshes in the list of object  :

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 50, 1 );
for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.faces.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
    face.vertexColors[ 0 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
    face.vertexColors[ 1 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
    face.vertexColors[ 2 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );

}

for ( var i = 0; i < list.length; i=i+2 ) {

    geometry.width = size_list[i];
    geometry.depth = size_list[i+1];

    console.log('geo');
    console.log(geometry.width);
    console.log(geometry.depth);

    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { specular: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.x = list[i];
    mesh.position.y = 5;
    mesh.position.z = list[i+1];

    console.log('mesh');
    console.log(mesh.geometry.width);
    console.log(mesh.geometry.depth);

    scene.add( mesh );

    material.color.setHSL( Math.random() * 0.2 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );

    objects.push( mesh );

}
```

All meshes are rectangles with different sizes. The sizes are stored in `size_list`. I am using only one `geometry` object because if I use more the program crash. I tried creating one geometry object per mesh by moving this

```
geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 50, 1 );
for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.faces.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var face = geometry.faces[ i ];
    face.vertexColors[ 0 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
    face.vertexColors[ 1 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );
    face.vertexColors[ 2 ] = new THREE.Color().setHSL( Math.random() * 0.3 + 0.5, 0.75, Math.random() * 0.25 + 0.75 );

}
```

into the second for loop but the browser couldn't handle it.

So I'm modifying the property of the `geometry` object before creating a mesh and pushing it to the object array. I'm logging the modified values so I can see that they are correctly changed as the good values are printed.

However, in the end, when displaying the scene, all the meshes still got the dimensions of (1, 50, 1) as defined in the first line of code snippet. I have been reading about javascript and I think the problem like in the way it handles copies and references but I can't really understand that behavior.

How can I effectively modify the meshes without have to create a new `geometry` object for every mesh ? And why does this method doesn't work ?

Comment: Try this: Create once: `var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );` Then in your loop: `mesh.scale.set( width[ i ], height[ i ], depth[ i ] );`

Comment: This does change the mesh dimension :). Thanks a lot. Could you maybe explain why the first version isn't working ?

Comment: The best answer I can give you is the library was not designed to work that way.

Comment: OK thanks. I though there could be a more "JavaScript" answer :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale a mesh by setting its `scale` property.

Use this pattern:

```
 var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ); // create once
```

Then in your loop:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material ); // share the geometry

mesh.scale.set( width[ i ], height[ i ], depth[ i ] );
```

three.js r.73